# limits_h macros on Windows (C)

Tags: c, variables, macros, limits

I ran the following C code on Windows 8.1 (x64) to get a better understanding of the lower and upper limits of the primitive data types but I find the output surprising.

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("\n");
    printf("Integer types");
    printf("\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf("Signed");
    printf("\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf("signed char:          %d to %d\n", SCHAR_MIN, SCHAR_MAX);
    printf("signed short int:     %d to %d\n", SHRT_MIN, SHRT_MAX);
    printf("signed int:           %d to %d\n", INT_MIN, INT_MAX);
    printf("signed long int:      %d to %d\n", LONG_MIN, LONG_MAX);
    printf("signed long long int: %d to %d\n", LLONG_MIN, LLONG_MAX);
    printf("\n");
    printf("Unsigned");
    printf("\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf("unsigned char:          0 to %d\n", UCHAR_MAX);
    printf("unsigned short int:     0 to %d\n", USHRT_MAX);
    printf("unsigned int:           0 to %d\n", UINT_MAX);
    printf("unsigned long int:      0 to %d\n", ULONG_MAX);
    printf("unsigned long long int: 0 to %d\n", ULLONG_MAX);
    printf("\n");
    printf("Platform dependant");
    printf("\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf("char: %d to %d\n", CHAR_MIN, CHAR_MAX);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

The following is the output:

Integer types

Signed

signed char: -128 to 127
signed short int: -32768 to 32767
signed int: -2147483648 to 2147483647
signed long int: -2147483648 to 2147483647
signed long long int: 0 to -1

Unsigned

unsigned char: 0 to 255
unsigned short int: 0 to 65535
unsigned int: 0 to -1
unsigned long int: 0 to -1
unsigned long long int: 0 to -1

Platform dependant

char: -128 to 127

What I didn't expect is that LLONG_MIN is 0 and LLONG_MAX is -1 and UINT_MAX, ULONG_MAX and ULLONG_MAX are -1. What is going on here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using the wrong format, `%d` expects `int`, try

```
printf("signed long int:      %ld to %ld\n", LONG_MIN, LONG_MAX);
printf("signed long long int: %lld to %lld\n", LLONG_MIN, LLONG_MAX);
```

and

```
printf("unsigned int:           0 to %u\n", UINT_MAX);
printf("unsigned long int:      0 to %lu\n", ULONG_MAX);
printf("unsigned long long int: 0 to %llu\n", ULLONG_MAX);
```

Comment: Of course, but why does it work for signed short int and unsigned short int?

Comment: @HelloWorld Two words: integer promotion.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that the format code `"%d"` is for the type `signed int`. For `long` you have to use the prefix `l`, like `"%ld"`, for `long long` you have to use `"%lld"`.

For `unsigned int` the format code is `"%u"`, and add prefix for `unsigned short`, `unsigned long` etc.

See e.g. [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf).

---

To be more precise about why you get `-1` for the max value, especially for the unsigned types, is because you print them as signed values, and the values are all binary ones which is `-1` in [two's complement systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) used by all modern systems.

Comment: Of course, but why does it work for signed short int and unsigned short int?

Comment: @HelloWorld Because of the nature of variable-argument functions, types smaller than `int` are promoted to `int`. While not official, see e.g. [this link](http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx11c.html).

Comment: That's weird but then again coming from a C# background everything about C is weird.